# Pivotal cloud foundry - Application listening on TCP port

Tags: tcp, routes, cloud-foundry

I am trying to run an test app on pivotal cloud foundry, that listens on TCP port 2222.  I was able to create a TCP route however i was not able to reach this server from a client outside, any ideas?  on the same vm i am able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to talk to your platform operator. In addition to mapping a TCP route to your app, you need to have load balancers configured to route TCP traffic into the platform.

Please check with your platform operator to see if the following steps have been performed.

https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-3/adminguide/enabling-tcp-routing.html